# Strange behaviour when renaming a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, change-script

I need to write some code for renaming a column in SQL Server 2008.
When scripting that in Management Studio I got a double renaming :

NAME1 ==> TEMPNAME ==> NAME2

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Table_1.columFirstName', N'Tmp_columSecondName_2', 'COLUMN' 
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Table_1.Tmp_columSecondName_2', N'columSecondName', 'COLUMN' 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

But when I do it in one go, It works just fine.

Why the column first is renamed to a temporary name?  Does it makes sense when  coding a renaming algoritm to do the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Great question - I've always wondered about this too!

Comment: I've got SSMS 2008 - how are you generating the script? I can't find the option..

Comment: After designing a table, a button next to the primary key button gets enabled.  A script Icon with a disk.  Click that to get the script of what will happen when you save.  (click it before you save)

Comment: It is also possible to enable generation of script on every save in Designer with the **Auto generate change scripts** option.  This option is available in **Tools** > **Options** > **Designers** > **Table and Database Designers** > checkbox of **Auto generate change scripts**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can swap column names between two columns. Management studio supports that by renaming all columns to temporary names, and then renaming them to the final names.

Blorgbeard: In the Design Window right-click menu, there is a generate change script choice.

Comment: It's not? Switch A and B, you need A to TMP, B to A, TMP to B. To shift A,B,C to B,C,A you would need A to TMP, C to A, B to C, B to TMP. To shift A,B,C to C,A,B you need A to TMP, B to A, C to B, TMP to C. This gets complex, so why not just do it the way they do it.

Comment: Okay, I see it now.. I didn't catch the phrase at first. Tx.

Comment: Interesting stuff - there are other places where SMSS generates more complex scripts than required in order to support more exotic scenarios, so your answer makes sense to me.